# how can i sample equal number of clusters with probability proportional to size with replacement (ppswr) from a very large number of stratas?

Tags: r, sample, stratum, pps

Trying to create a sample clusters selected through pps with replacement. for very particular reasons this study has to have a total of 412 stratas (each a combination of the name of the township, the urban/rural attribute and the conflict status attribute) the sample is a master list of the population of clusters with their corresponding strata information stored in the column "composite." i used to `pps` package and sorted the sample according to composite.

```
>samplesort1<-sample_data[order(sample_data$composite),]
```

and then tried to select 16 clusters through pps with replacement from each of the 412 stratas.

```
clustersample<-samplesort1[ppssstrat(permuteinstrata(samplesort1$`Sum of Admin4HHNum`),samplesort1$composite,c(16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16)),]
```

in the output i should get a table with 412*16=6592 observations. instead i am getting a file with 1616 observations. when i look into the file i find that 16 clusters each from 101 strata. can somebody help me correct this?

Thanksssss!

i'm not really trained in using R, so there could be many reasons for this error. but i really need to compute this data and generate a list of selected clusters. please help!